# Why does the Linux kernel enable interrupts in preempt_schedule_irq?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, interrupt

I'm reading Linux source code to learn how scheduling works. I learn that in a preemptible kernel (`CONFIG_PREEMPT` is set), there is a chance for preemption after returning to kernel-space from interrupt handler by calling `preempt_schedule_irq`.

However, I also find the following code snippet in [preempt_schedule_irq](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.14/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L3606)

```
do {
    preempt_disable();
    local_irq_enable(); //why enable interrupt here?
    __schedule(true); //interrupt would be disabled inside it
    local_irq_disable();
    sched_preempt_enable_no_resched();
} while (need_resched());
```

There is a `local_irq_enable()` call inside it and this kind of confuses me. Why do we need to enable interrupt here since [at the start of `__schedule` it would disabled again](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.14/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L3294)?.

My humble guess is that this gives a chance to processes with higher priority to be scheduled first. However, it doesn't make sense because the preemption is already disabled in `preempt_schedule_irq`, even if there is an interrupt, there would not be a preemption reschedule.

So what on earth is the point in preempting the scheduling procedure here? I think I must have missed something but I don't figure out.

Comment: Isn't it related to priority inversion?

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I didn't know this so I'll look into it.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Hi, I did some search yesterday, but I still don't quite understand how it is related to priority inversion. I dont see where its priority is changed, how does enabling interrupt help prevent this situation? Suppose there are 3 processes, whose priorities are A < B < C, so A is holding some resources. Even if A does not release these resources, I think B will not be able to schedule ahead of C because preemption is disabled. Whenever preemption is enabled again, the schduler will schedule C first? I'm note sure because I'm quite a newbie in scheduling.

Comment: I don't understand myself what all of this is intented for but as you thought it may be something related to high priority first scheduling I thought about priority inversion problem. At first sight all of this seems strange and not useful but I doubt it is.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Because interrupts should be enabled as much as possible, only disabled to protect minimal critical sections. Arbitrarily extending the disabling beyond your critical section into non-critical sections of functions you're calling because you're assuming that at some point that function will disable them, is bad design.

Why doesn't __schedule() disable interrupts as it's very first instruction? Because it doesn't need to, the code at the start of __schedule() isn't a critical section so explicitly disabling interrupts before it would be a waste. The writer of __schedule() went out of their way to maximize the time when interrupts can be handled, why ignore that opportunity by not enabling interrupts?

Also, you have no guarantees about what __schedule() might do in the future. Since the start of __schedule() isn't a critical section, you have no guarantees that more stuff won't be added before the interrupt disabling. Remember, the person who's going to be making changes to __schedule() shouldn't have to consider that one of the callers decided to leave their interrupts disabled relying on the fact that __schedule() turns them off pretty soon anyway. __schedule() has no regard at all about interrupt status when it's called.

You should disable/enable interrupts around the critical sections of your code, not rely on the inner mechanics of some other function you're calling and hoping it doesn't change.

If you look through the history of the scheduler, you'll see that the code preceding the interrupt disabling has changed over time. Digging through the commits you see that the "sti" to enable interrupts was present since the very first commit to implement preemption in the kernel going back all the way to 2.5: https://github.com/schwabe/tglx-history/blob/ec332cd30cf1ccde914a87330ff66744414c8d24/arch/i386/kernel/entry.S#L235